# WPF Progress Bar called by Class Library

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a WPF Project for progress bar. Currently it will show progress based on static value and the progress will be called as "contentrendered"

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```

I'm thinking about to intergrate this project into my Class Library Project. This class library will download a file from server. I've tried a few way but still not success. Anyone can help me?

```
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

            for (int i = 0; i < fileName.Count; i++)
            {
                myStringWebResource = uri + fileName[i];
                myStringTempResource = appPath + "\\temp\\" + fileName[i];

                myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, myStringTempResource);

                //worker.ProgressChanged += updateMgrProgress.worker_ProgressChanged;
            }
```

Comment: When you say "I've tried a few way but still not success" - do you get a specific error when you do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right you should write this

```
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();

for (int i = 0; i < fileName.Count; i++)
{
    myStringWebResource = uri + fileName[i];
    myStringTempResource = appPath + "\\temp\\" + fileName[i];

    myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource, myStringTempResource);

    (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
}
```

in

```
worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
```

and just report the value of `i` like you did it in your example.

And by the way `ProgressBar` has a property `IsIndeterminate` you can use it too.